# Recursive async/await crashes React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, async-await, mergesort

I'm trying to create a React App which models various sorting algorithms with various parameters.  I'm trying to create a variable delay at each step of the algorithm in order to let it occur at a human-understandable speed.  I've written this sleep function to do it:

```
sleep = (ms = this.state.delay) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Then create an `async` sorting function which `await this.sleep()` as necessary.  It works for bubble sort, selection sort, and insertion sort, but the app crashes when I try merge sort.  I assume it's due to recursion, but I'm pretty stumped.

```
async mergeSort(arr) {
    if(arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
    }
    const m = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    let left = arr.slice(0, m);
    let right = arr.slice(m);

    await this.sleep();

    return this.merge(this.mergeSort(left), this.mergeSort(right));


}

async merge(left, right) {
    let result = [];

    while(left.length && right.length) {
        if(left[0].props.number <= right[0].props.number) {
            result.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            result.push(right.shift());
        }
        await this.sleep();
    }

    while(left.length) {
        result.push(left.shift());
        await this.sleep();
    }

    while(right.length) {
        result.push(right.shift());
        await this.sleep();
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

But I'm not assigning the Promises as elements to be rendered, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

EDIT:  Here is the render method:

```
render() {
    let {sorted, hatArray, sortingMethod, startTime, endTime, numberOfHats, sorting} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <SortMenu 
                onOptionSelect={this.onOptionSelect} 
                onSortBtn={this.onSortBtn} 
                onHatInputChange={this.onHatInputChange}
                updateHatArray={this.updateHatArray}
                setDelay={this.setDelay}
                sorting={sorting}
            />
            <Modal 
                open={sorted} 
                onClose={this.onCloseModal} 
                classNames={{
                    modal: 'custom-modal',
                    closeIcon: 'modal-close-button'
                }}
                center 
            >
                <h1>Sorting Complete!</h1>
                <p>{`${sortingMethod} sorted ${numberOfHats} hats in ${(endTime - startTime) / 1000} seconds.`}</p>
            </Modal>
            <div id="hat-box">
                {hatArray}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Provide your render method as well as the error occurs there.

Comment: Done!  I wonder if the recursion is not waiting for the Promise to resolve or something, so it passes unresolved promises to render method

Comment: Hm and which method uses the merge method ?

Comment: The problem is that you're rendering the result of merge method which is a Promise (like with every async function). Instead update the state inside the merge method (after every push) and render the result accordingly.

Comment: 'I'm not assigning the Promises as elements' -- in fact you are, `merge` and `mergeSort` return promises implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!  Thanks to user3210641 and Lyosha Korogada for the input.

I changed the merge sort so it wasn't returning a value, but rather altering another array.  Then I set the state to that array as I went.

If the sleep function is put inside the `merge()` function, it messes up the sort order, but I was able to put it in the `mergeSort()` function with a variable number of seconds to achieve the same result.

```
async mergeSort(l, r) {
    if(l < r) {
        console.log(l);
        const m = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);
        this.mergeSort(l, m);
        this.mergeSort(m + 1, r);
        await this.sleep((r - l) * this.state.delay);
        this.merge(l, m, r);    
    }
}

merge(l, m, r) {
    let left = this.globalHatArray.slice(l, m + 1);
    let right = this.globalHatArray.slice(m + 1, r + 1);
    let ptr = l;
    while(left.length && right.length) {
        if(left[0].props.number <= right[0].props.number) {
            this.globalHatArray[ptr] = left.shift();
        } else {
            this.globalHatArray[ptr] = right.shift();
        }
        ptr++;
    }

    while(left.length) {
        this.globalHatArray[ptr] = left.shift();
        ptr++;
    }

    while(right.length) {
        this.globalHatArray[ptr] = right.shift();
        ptr++;
    }
    this.setState({hatArray: this.globalHatArray});
}
```